# How to pass value between jsp file and java file?

Tags: spring-mvc

How do I pass variable from JSP page to Java file in spring? Welcome.jsp is the jsp page 
<%    String empId=request.getParameter("empId" );
  out.println("Welcome  User "+empId); %> 
   
      
how to pass value of empId to java file??

Comment: You question is *unclear*. Maybe you should first read the doc, because Spring Framework Reference Manual has plenty of nice examples.

Answer (score 0):

Already you have value in Request Parameter.

Use

```
@RequestParam("empid")String empId
```